# Sum of Telescopic Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, telescopic-series

**Question :**

> $$\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{(r^2-r-1)}{(r+1)!}=?$$

I tried but I got $(-1)!$ in the end. This is what I tried:

$$
\require{cancel}
\frac{r^2-1}{(r+1)!}-\frac{r}{(r+1)!}\\
\frac{\cancel{(r+1)}\cancel{(r-1)}}{\cancel{(r+1)}r\cancel{(r-1)}(r-2)!}-\frac{\cancel{r}}{(r+1)\cancel{r}(r-1)!}\\
T_r=\frac{1}{r(r-2)!}-\frac{1}{(r+1)(r-1)!}\\
\sum_{r=1}^{n} T_r = \frac{1}{1(1-2)!}-\frac{1}{(n+1)(n-1)!}\\
= \frac{1}{(-1)!}-\frac{1}{(n+1)(n-1)!}\\
$$

Please point out my mistake.

Comment: Please show what you have done.

Comment: how did you get (-1)!

Comment: Find $a,b,c$ such that $r^2-r-1=ar(r+1)+b(r+1)+c$, identically.

Comment: "I am taught in school that after splitting the fractions. Put the minima in least denominator and maxima in greater denominator." That is not a good way to teach.

Comment: Since $\frac1{(-1)!}=\frac0{0!}=0$, your answer is correct, in a sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\frac{r^2-r-1}{(r+1)!}&=&\frac{r^2-1}{(r+1)!}-\frac{r}{(r+1)!}\\&=&\frac{(r-1)(r+1)}{(r+1)!}-\frac{r}{(r+1)!}\\&=&\frac{r-1}{r!}-\frac{r}{(r+1)!}\end{eqnarray*}$$

Therefore:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{(r^2-r-1)}{(r+1)!}&=&\sum_{r=1}^n\left[\frac{r-1}{r!}-\frac{r}{(r+1)!}\right]\\&=&\frac{0}{1!}-\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{2}{3!}+\frac{2}{3!}-\frac{3}{4!}+...+\frac{n-1}{n!}-\frac{n}{(n+1)!}\\&=&\color{blue}{-\frac{n}{(n+1)!}}\end{eqnarray*}$$

Answer (score 4):

For any $n\geq 2$ we have
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{r^2-r-1}{(r+1)!}&=&\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{(r+1)r}{(r+1)!}-2\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{(r+1)}{(r+1)!}+\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(r+1)!}\\&=&\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(r-1)!}-2\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{1}{r!}+\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(r+1)!}\\
&=&\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{r!}-2\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{1}{r!}+\sum_{r=2}^{n+1}\frac{1}{r!}\\&=&\frac{1}{0!}-\frac{1}{1!}-\frac{1}{n!}+\frac{1}{(n+1)!}=\color{red}{-\frac{n}{(n+1)!}}.\end{eqnarray*}$$